# StrongNamer.AddStrongName task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have downloaded solution. Unsigned the Assemblies,Provided Amazon Key and Secret Statically and build the solution and got error as below -

StrongNamer.AddStrongName task failed unexpectedly.....

There is no specific codeline where this error is coming it is coming while I build solution.
you can find solution and code here - https://github.com/Rambalac/ACDDokanNet

What could be possible solution to it ?

Please find below complete Details of errror

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   The "StrongNamer.AddStrongName" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'DokanNet, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cef3dedf553bda55'
at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve(TypeReference type)
at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
at Mono.Cecil.Mixin.CheckedResolve(TypeReference self)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.GetConstantType(TypeReference constant_type, Object constant)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddConstant(IConstantProvider owner, TypeReference type)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddField(FieldDefinition field)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddFields(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddType(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddTypeDefs()
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildTypes()
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildModule()
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildMetadata()
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.<>c.b__1_0(MetadataBuilder builder, MetadataReader _)
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet](TItem item, Func3 read) at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.BuildMetadata(ModuleDefinition module, MetadataBuilder metadata) at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModuleTo(ModuleDefinition module, Disposable1 stream, WriterParameters parameters)
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters)
at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters)
at StrongNamer.AddStrongName.ProcessAssembly(ITaskItem assemblyItem, StrongNameKeyPair key)
at StrongNamer.AddStrongName.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() Cloud.DokanNet.Gui
```

Answer (score 2):

The real error is in there.

```
Failed to resolve assembly: 'DokanNet, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cef3dedf553bda55'
```